# Limiting Redis user and/or namespace storage sizes

Tags: redis

I am trying to set up a Redis system where I have some users and some namespaces where for each namespace there is only one user that have write access, the others can only read. Available memory is limited and I want to make sure a single user/namespaces does not take all the memory and starve the others.

Since data is randomly written and needs to be retained as long as the producer wants it too (as long as it stays within some predefined storage size limit), I don't think I can use any of the built-in LRU eviction policies.

So is there a way to implement quotas for each user or each namespace, or a way to define an eviction policy that evicts the offending namespace's data only? I can't find any configuration options that suits my needs, but possibly this can be solved by building a plugin?

Comment: You can use redis as a shared LRU cache and send any evicted data to a normal database hdd/ssd. This way, idle user data would stay in database hdd while working user data would stay in redis. Then, you could have another layer of caching but on client computer, to give them their own RAM. What does offender mean here? Spammers? Idlers?